# Sum involving Stirling's numbers of the second kind

Tags: summation, stirling-numbers

I was reading one book about basic probability theory and came across one problem that caught my attention.  [Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTw1v.png)
So in the end there is a sum of the form: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i}\binom{n}{i}(1-\frac{i}{n})^k$.
The author then says that in fact, this is just $\frac{n!}{n^k}S_{n,k}$, where $S_{n,k}$ is [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). I don't understand how he simplified the sum. Please help.
P.S. Sorry if the question is a bit stupid.

Comment: Which *definition* of $S_{n,k}$ do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this as
$$n! S_{n,k}=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}i(n-i)^k.\tag{*}$$
This is a slightly eccentric notation for the Stirling numbers, as
we have to interpret $S_{n,k}$ as the number of partitions of $[k]=\{1,\ldots,k\}$
into $n$ non-empty parts.

In (*) both sides count the number of surjections from $[k]$ to $[n]$.
The LHS is pretty much by definition, the RHS uses inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that. But I would like to show this equation formally by simplifying the given sum so that it becomes $S_{n,k}$.